# Filter pairs of elements so that each element occurs in only one pair

Tags: r, igraph

I have a data frame containing pairs of interacting elements. I want to filter the pairs so that each element occurs in only one pair. Which pair is kept for each element should be randomly selected.

```
df <- data.frame(element1=c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D"), 
                 element2=c("B","C","D","E","C","D","E","F"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Example input:

```
Element1   Element2   
A          B        
A          C   
B          D       
B          E
B          C
C          D
C          E 
D          F
```

Desired output e.g.:

```
Element1   Element2   
A          B
C          E
D          F
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This can get crazy complicated. For instance, if `filter(!element2 %in% element1)`, then you will never see `A` in the first column; similarly, if `filter(!element1 %in% element2)`, you only get two combinations: `A,B` and `A,C`. I think you can be a little more clear on how to determine in which column a letter should belong.

Comment: Also you do not want any letter to repeat more than once? Like A,B and next row D,A? Is it fine for the A to repeat in multiple rows?

Comment: The issue is that my real data refers to interacting genes, therefore there is no real reason why an element should be in column 1 or column 2. At the moment they are sorted into column 1 if they are alphabetically first. I could arbitrarily define this in another way.

Comment: This is tricky---are you sure a solution even exists in your full data? In your sample data, `F`  only occurs once, so that `D,F` pair must be kept, so then all other `D` occurrences must be dropped. What if `G` only occurred once and was also paired with `D`? You have the choice of repeating `D` or omitting `F` or `G`...

Comment: I don't know the terminology for this particular problem, but it seems like `igraph` might have something that would work. Treat each element as a node, and each pair as an edge between the nodes, you want to drop edges such that each node is only connected to one other.

Comment: @Gregor in that case I would want to omit either F or G randomly rather than repeating D. I think the solution should exist as long as I am prepared to sacrifice data.

Comment: @XXavier I want each element to occur only once, so only AB or DA could be kept

Comment: Added `igraph` tag, can't fully see how it can be done, but getting a feeling this is the job for igraph, hope ok.

Comment: can you share some statistics of your actual dataset? e.g. nrow, num of unique elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `igraph` method, that isn't smart about keeping the most data. But it will guarantee a maximum of one connection per element.

```
library(igraph)
gr <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)

for (vertex in sample(V(gr))) {
  if (degree(gr)[vertex] > 1) {
    edges <- E(gr)[.inc(vertex)]
    to_remove <- sample(edges, length(edges) - 1)
    gr <- delete_edges(gr, to_remove)
  }
}
as_data_frame(gr)
```

You can maybe do a bit better when ordering the vertices beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this exactly answers your question, but here's a way to choose the first occurrence of each element. It keeps the uniqueness that you mentioned but it is not randomly chosen.

```
    new_e1 <- c()
    new_e2 <- c()

    for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        e1 <- df[i, "element1"]
        e2 <- df[i, "element2"]
        if (!(e1 %in% new_e1) && !(e2 %in% new_e2) &&
            !(e1 %in% new_e2) && !(e2 %in% new_e1)) {
                new_e1 <- c(new_e1, e1)
                new_e2 <- c(new_e2, e2)
        }
    }

    new_df <- data.frame(element1 = new_e1, element2 = new_e2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am sure that there are smarter ways to write this code, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For this toy example, you can approach it as an optimization problem with binary variables representing which rows are chosen, and constraints such that each variable is chosen once.

```
el <- sort(unique(c(df$element1, df$element2)))
A <- matrix(0L, nrow=length(el), ncol=nrow(df), dimnames=list(el, sample(nrow(df))))
i <- match(unlist(df), rownames(A))
j <- match(rep(1L:nrow(df), ncol(df)), colnames(A))
A[cbind(i, j)] <- 1L

ans <- lp(direction="min",
    objective.in=rep(1L, nrow(df)),
    const.mat=A,
    const.dir="==",
    const.rhs=rep(1L, length(el)),
    all.bin=TRUE)
df[colnames(A)[as.logical(ans$solution)], ]
```

output:

```
  element1 element2
2        A        C
4        B        E
8        D        F
```